# CSS Sprite only showing final image

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I have a sprite sheet and I want to display images next to each other but the code is only displaying the final image. So this code displays only the google image but it does display it correctly (with a:hover) but it doesn't display the facebook or twitter images.

I know the co-ordinates are correct and if I comment out the google `<li>` when I refresh the page only the facebook image shows. I can not figure out what is wrong with it but wondered if it had something to do with the display property?

EDIT: Here is a live example of what's happening:  **http://jsfiddle.net/Duykb/**

```
<div class="social"><h3>SHARE THIS PAGE</h3>
     <ul id="social">
         <li class="facebook">
             <a href="#" title="Facebook"></a></li>
         <li class="twitter">
             <a href="#" title="Twitter"></a></li>
         <li class="google">
             <a href="#" title="Google+"></a></li> 
    </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
h3 {
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 16px; }

#social {
margin-top: 10px;   
display: block;
position:relative;
padding-top: 30px; }        

#social li {
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
position:absolute;
top:0; }

#social li, #social a {
height:37px;
display:block; }


ul#social li.facebook a {
background: url('images/social_icons.png') no-repeat -5px -4px;
width: 37px;
height: 37px; }

ul#social li.facebook a:hover {
background: url('images/social_icons.png') no-repeat -5px -42px;
width: 37px;
height: 37px; }

ul#social li.twitter a {
background: url('images/social_icons.png') no-repeat -45px -4px;
width: 37px;
height: 37px; }

ul#social li.twitter a:hover {
background: url('images/social_icons.png') no-repeat -45px -42px;
width: 37px;
height: 37px; }

ul#social li.google a {
background: url('images/social_icons.png') no-repeat -82px -4px;
width: 37px;
height: 37px; }

ul#social li.google a:hover {
background: url('images/social_icons.png') no-repeat -82px -42px;
width: 37px;
height: 37px; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Duykb/1/

Removed `position: absolute` and `top: 0` from `#social li`, and then added...

```
#social li {
    float: left;
    width: 37px;
}
```

Then make necessary adjustments to `#social` for proper position on page.

Comment: Thank you, yes float:left instead of position:absolute worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `<li>`'s are all sitting on top of one another due to their absolute positioning. Therefore, you're dealing with a layering issue.

If you'd like them all positioned next to each other, try setting a width to each of the block elements and give them an absolute position using the `left:` or `right:` properties.

EDIT:

Change the `#social li` rule to...

```
    #social li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    width: 37px;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Duykb/2/

Comment: There's no way to really verify what he's seeing, because we don't have the sprite sheet to look at.  He did mention that things change when he comments out the last <li> though, which leads me to believe that they're sitting on top of one another.

Comment: ...Or just float:left instead of absolute positioning.

Comment: Right, float is an option here as well.  There are a few choices on the table.

Comment: we don't need the sprite sheet to know there's a positioning problem. There is, and the spriting is irrelevant to the fix.